# Staging dataflow template job fails

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow

Following dataflow [Creating Templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/creating-templates) guide, I've created this simple example of template dataflow job:

```
public class Runner {
  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final PlaygroundPipelineOptions options =
        PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(PlaygroundPipelineOptions.class);

    options.setRunner(TemplatingDataflowPipelineRunner.class);
    options.setZone("***");
    options.setNetwork("***");
    options.setSubnetwork("***");
    options.setStagingLocation("***");
    options.setDataflowJobFile("***");

    final Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

    pipeline
        .apply(TextIO.Read.from(options.getInput()).named("TextIO.Read"))
        .apply(MapElements.via(new SimpleFunction<String, String>() {
          @Override
          public String apply(String input) {
            return input.toUpperCase();
          }
        }))
        .apply(TextIO.Write.to(options.getOutput()).named("TextIO.Write"));

    pipeline.run();
  }

  private interface PlaygroundPipelineOptions extends DataflowPipelineOptions {
    @Description("Input path")
    @Validation.Required
    ValueProvider<String> getInput();

    void setInput(ValueProvider<String> input);

    @Description("Output path")
    @Validation.Required
    ValueProvider<String> getOutput();

    void setOutput(ValueProvider<String> input);
  }
}
```

But after trying to run it it fails with the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot validate with a filepattern provided at runtime.
```

The problem is when `ValueProvider#get()` is called, but what's the proper way to stage a template job and not have these errors?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be coming from [TextIO source](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/TextIO.java#L320). The solution is likely to disable validation of the `TextIO` source by calling `withoutValidation()` since the filepattern isn't available during validation.

Comment: that's exactly what I did as an ad hoc solution, but by reading the guide and about templating the jobs sdk should handle this appropriately. The general issue it that ValueProvider#isAccessible() returns false, same as that ValueProvider#get() throws an exception.

Comment: I believe that may just be missing documentation. Validation runs when the pipeline template is being created. Since the value of the filepattern isn't available until the pipeline template is being used to run a job, it is not accessible and cannot be validated while creating the template. Hence the error (which should be clarified).